# Get images from nginex dynamic path

Tags: nginx

When requesting an image from a URL, nginex does not find an address with images, I get a 404 error

Path pattern /images/d8f7fe68-bf44-44ea-b01d-1a8eb91ffa06/computer.png

Where the Guid will change depending on the product **d8f7fe68-bf44-44ea-b01d-1a8eb91ffa06**

I tried to implement it using a regular expression

```
location ~ ^/images/[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }
```

How to correctly register the location? To access images.

Comment: Test your Nginx configuration using `nginx -t`. BTW, a regular expression containing `{` needs to be enclosed within quotes.